# mysql_fetch_length equivalent function in CodeIgniter ?

Tags: php, codeigniter, string-length

I want to count how many characters are generated by a database query.
In PHP I'm using `mysql_fetch_length`. Is there an equivalent function in CodeIgniter?

Comment: first of all stop using/talking about mysql* family

Answer (score 0):

"In Codeigniter" is to php as "with jquery" is to javascript, these days. It's just php.

No, CI doesn't have this. Return a row_array() and then:

```
$row_array = ['test', 'this'];

$new_total = array_sum(array_map(function($value){$total = strlen($value);return $total;}, $row_array));
var_dump($new_total);
```